# How to get the values from multiple form in one post request using laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#finalSubmit').click(function() {


            var form1 = $('#priceform').serialize();
            var form2 = $('#formdescription').serialize();
            var form3 = $('#additionaldescription').serialize();
    //var form4 = new FormData($("#imagesform").get(0));
    //alert(form4);

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
                $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
            });

            $.ajax({
                url      :"{{url('/dbvalue')}}",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {form1: form1, form2: form2,form3: form3},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);

                }

            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my ajax code.Here I'm passing the values of four forms

Controller:

```
public function finalSubmit(Request $request)
{      

    var_dump($_POST);
    $var1 = $this->addPriceDetails1($request->form1);

    $var2 = $this->addProductDetails1($request->form2);
    $var3 = $this->addAdditionalInformation1($request->form3);
        //$var4 = $this->addImages($imagesform);//you dont't have 
    $imagesform
    return response()->json(["response"=>"success"]);
}
```

Eg. for function:

```
public function addPriceDetails1($request)
{

    $priceInfo = new priceInfo ;
    $priceInfo->id=$this->getpriceDetailsId();
    $priceInfo->SKUID=$request->input('skuid');
    echo($priceInfo->id);

     //return $request->all();
}
```

Also here when I'm trying to echo the values of `$priceInfo->Id` it echoes '0'.I don't know why

With this I'm getting FatalErrorException..`call to member function input() on string`[image: shows my error details]

`var_dump($_POST)`  gives me an array of forms values.

UPdate:

```
  public function getpriceDetailsId()
 {
  $id = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
  $id="PD".$id;
  $count=priceInfo::select('id')->where('id',$id)->count();
  if($count==0)
  {
    return $id;
  }
  else
  {
    $this->getpriceDetailsId();
  }
  }
```

here is my function for getpriceDetailsId().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because your input query when you access as `object` when it is `string`, you can convert your query string to an array to access like so.

```
public function addPriceDetails1($request)
{
    parse_str($request, $input);
    $priceInfo = new priceInfo ;
    $priceInfo->id = $this->getpriceDetailsId();
    $priceInfo->SKUID = $input['skuid'];
    echo($priceInfo->id);
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: It works..But I'm not getting the value for `$priceInfo->id`

Comment: Well, for this you need show me where the `getpriceDetailsId()` is? Is on same controller or other?

Comment: Why you rand your ID? Is your ID is not `int` because I see you add string into it `$id="PD".$id;`?, and why you only return your `$id` when is 0 `if($count==0)`? I don't know why you write this function and its purpose ^^

Comment: yes..my ID is string..and I'm returning it when $count==0 bcz that id should not be repeated

Comment: I don't know your system so I can't help you with your function because I don't know what is use for.

Comment: I'm just appending with the randomly generated id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154114/discussion-between-nishanthi-and-vietnguyen09).

Comment: Here,it only get the values of input fields...not getting the values of dropdown